# Seaborn line graph for dataframe based on filters

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I hope to plot a line graph with the following conditions: Race == ALL, Year == 2020 for age group index 0 to 14 and columns 0 Child to 5 or more child.

I have tried the following code but it does not work.

```
PopulationCensusCombined['Age Group'].iloc[0:15]
ChildColumns = PopulationCensusCombined.columns[4:].to_list()
PopulationCensusCombined[ChildColumns]
PopulationCensusCombined.shape #output (150,10)

sns.lineplot(
    data=PopulationCensusCombined.query(("Race == 'ALL' & Year==2020")),
    x = PopulationCensusCombined[ChildColumns],
    y=PopulationCensusCombined['Age Group'].iloc[0:15], 
    style="choice",
    palette="flare")
```

The following error was:

ValueError: Length of DataFrame vectors must match length of `data` when both are used, but `data` has length 15 and the vector passed to `x` has length 150.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is just as the error says.

*data* and *x* components have different dimensions.

Due to the below query,

```
PopulationCensusCombined.query(("Race == 'ALL' & Year==2020"))
```

*data* receieves only 15 rows(as per the image of the dataframe), whereas x considers all 150 rows of the original dataframe, leading to the mismatch. Assigning *ChildColumns* of only 15 rows to *x* should solve your problem.